# Given independent events find $P(A\mid A\cup B)$

Tags: probability, statistics

Given that $P(A) = 0.8$, $P(B) = 0.5$ and $A$ and $B$ are independent events,
find $P(A \mid A \cup B)$

The way I tried solving this is by doing: $P(A \cap (A \cup B)) / P (A \cup B)$ which is equivalent to $P[(A \cap A) \cup (A \cap B)]/ P(A \cup B)$ which is equivalent to $P(A \cup (A \cap B)) / P(A \cup B)$.

Apparently, my friend tells me that its actually $P(A) / P(A \cup B)$ instead of $P[(A \cap (A \cup B))] / P (A \cup B)$ but he can't tell me why its $P(A) / P(A \cup B)$.

can someone help me if his way is correct or my way is correct? and in case his way is correct, can you please explain to me how $P(A \mid A \cup B)$ became $P (A) / P(A \cup B)$?.

Comment: To typeset equations, visit [this guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may notice that $A\subseteq A\cup B$ and so $A\cap (A\cup B)=A$  Similarly $A\cap B\subseteq A$ so $(A\cap B)\cup A = A$.

In general, $E\subseteq F$ if and only if $E\cap F = E$ if and only if $E\cup F=F$

As such, both your and your friend's expressions are correct, but his is easier to manage.

You have it good so far, all that remains is to calculate what $P(A\cup B)$ is.

Remember your inclusion-exclusion principle that $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$

To calculate $P(A\cap B)$ remember what it means to have two events be independent.

Answer (score 0):

$A\cup (A\cap B)=A$ because any element that is either in $A$, or both in $A$ and in $B$, is simply in $A$; and any element that is in $A$ is certainly in $A$ or elsewhere.

$A\cap (A\cup B)=A$ because any element that is both in $A$, and either in $A$ or in $B$, is surely in $A$; and any element that is in $A$ is certainly both in $A$, and either in $A$ or in $B$.

$\therefore \mathsf P(A\mid A\cup B) = \dfrac{\mathsf P(A)}{\mathsf P(A\cup B)}$